# How do I move a "submit" button to the right of the HTML page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I move a "submit" button to the right of the HTML page? It seems that the last radio option is squished together with the last submit button. I have tried adding break, but it dosent work

```
{%extends "new_base.html"%}
{%block content%}
<style> a.mylinklist{
    display:block;
}
</style>
 <div class="wrap size-1 " >
            <h2><strong>Question...</strong>click on the correct answer!</h2>
            <a href = "{{url_for("index")}}">back to home</a>
            <div class = "container" style="width:30%;margin:auto">
              <img style="width:100%;height:100%%;object-fit: cover;" src="{{url_for("static", filename="images/" + image)}}"></div></h2>
              <br>
            <div class="bg-white shadow" style="text-align:center">
              <ul class="flexblock reasons" style="height:100%">
            
            <h2 >
                  <p>{{question}}</p>
            </h2>
              {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                  {% if messages %}
                  {% for msg in messages %}
                  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
                  {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}
                  {% endwith %}
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <form class="longform" method="POST" action="#" style="margin:auto;display:flex">
                  {%for opt in options%}
                  <input class="form-control" type="radio" name="answer" value="{{opt}}" style="display:align;flex-grow:1">
                  {{options[opt]}}
                  </input>
                  {%endfor%}

                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" method="POST" style="width:25%;text-align:center;">SUBMIT </button>
                  
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: float to right ... [see here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Bootstrap so I assume you have access to all classes in the library. You can edit your submit method as follows;

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit" method="POST">SUBMIT </button>
```

I removed the inline CSS, if you want additional styling you may still add it.

Comment: Hi i tried ur suggestion, i still have the same problem. Please see the screenshots attached. The first screenshot with 2 submit buttons has the old and the new buttons, while the second contains only the new submit button. It seems that the button will auto align itself? https://imgur.com/a/wdjv7LM

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you can use this class float right as

```
<button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit" method="POST" style="width:25%;text-align:center;">SUBMIT </button>
```

to know more about bootstrap float classes check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

you can also do it without bootstrap like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" method="POST" style="width:25%;text-align:center;float-right">SUBMIT </button>
```

to know more about css float property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

The html shared by you is having multiple issues such as an unnecessary closing h2 tag, you should also have a look at [self-closing tags](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

if you are still unable to move your button to right, try update replacing your form opening tag with this

```
<form class="longform" method="POST" action="#" style="margin: auto">
```